# Running PHP task from cron: which IP will be submitted?

Tags: php, cron, ip

I have a PHP script that is called from cron on my server and sends sports results to my Twitter account.

Which IP address will Twitter save for this access? And other services as well?

Comment: http://www.davidc.net/networking/ipv6-source-address-selection-linux - that's for IPv6 but possibly it's similar for IPv4.

Comment: You could run a cron task that fetches `whatismyip.com` and saves the page onto your computer. You can then find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address of the server that the cronjob runs on.

Comment: He most likely has more than one IP

Comment: @ThiefMaster - yes, they probably do. But the IP address for my script would be still the same, right? Because the the script is placed on one server.

Comment: Servers may have more than one IP. Servers may be behind NAT (made accessible with port forwarding). Servers may be configured to use an HTTP proxy.